# Using sed in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to insert a line of text under a line of existing text in a file as per the following excerpt:

```
#!/bin/bash

MATCH='Text_To_Look_For'
INSERT='Text_To_Add'
FILE='/home/user/test.txt'


echo "Modifying file..."
sed -i 's/"$MATCH/$MATCH"\n"$INSERT"/' $FILE

echo "Done."
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of `/` `'` and `"` but cant seem to  make it work. The script will run now but not insert anything. In other formats I keep getting errors relating to:

> unterminated s command
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Remove the outer single quotes and try again.

Comment: OK, now you can see that you are using the `s` (substitute) command with no replacement.  The syntax is `s/from/to/`

Comment: I tried removing outer quotes so the line reads `sed -i s/"$MATCH/$MATCH"\n"$INSERT"/ $FILE` and get the error: **sed: -e expression #1, char 160: unknown option to `s'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what version of sed you're using, I've seen something similar on MacOS, where the standard sed is rather poor... Worked around by installing a GNU Sed (invoked later as `gsed`).

Anyway, can you give a try with sed `a` command (which stands for *append*):

```
#!/bin/bash

MATCH='Text_To_Look_For'
INSERT='Text_To_Add'
FILE='/tmp/xxx'


echo "Modifying file..."
sed -i "/$MATCH/a $INSERT" $FILE

echo "Done."
```

Best regards,
Jarek

Comment: Thanks @Jarek. That really helped. As you have written the sed line it does not actually save the changes to $FILE. I added -i and it now does save the changes. So the correct line is `sed -i "/$MATCH/a $INSERT" $FILE` or `-i.bak` to make a backup.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing out! Updated in the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` option to `sed` should be followed by a file extension, see `man sed`:  *-i extension - Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.*

It is trying to use your `s` command as a filename extension!

Try this:

```
sed -i .bak s/$MATCH/$MATCH\n$INSERT/ "$FILE"
```

Note that the `-i` option is non-standard and `sed` versions vary. For example you might have to remove the space:

```
sed -i.bak s/$MATCH/$MATCH\n$INSERT/ "$FILE"
```

An alternative to the `-i` is:

```
if sed s/$MATCH/$MATCH\n$INSERT/ "$FILE" > "$FILE.bak"
then
    mv "$FILE.bak" "$FILE"
fi
```

Comment: If I change it to the above I get the error **sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'**

Comment: Are you sure that your `sed` supports `-i`?  It is non-standard.  Try removing the `-i .bak`, the output will be written to stdout.  See also my edit.

Comment: Also try:  `sed -i.bak s/$MATCH/$MATCH\n$INSERT/ "$FILE"`

Comment: thanks for all the advice but any change I make as advised above I end up with **sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command** - I am sure this should not be difficult to achieve but it seems so... In case it matters it is a Debian machine running Stretch and I am ssh'ing into it from a Mac...

Comment: The trouble is that there are many version of `sed` (I tested on OS X) and, as I said, the `-i` option is non-standard.  If you want to be portable then don't use `-i`.  However, the `unterminated 's' command ` usually means you missed out the final /